# List assignment index out of range in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Given an integer array nums, return an array answer such that answer[i] is equal to the product of all the elements of nums except nums[i].

Example 1:

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: [24,12,8,6]
```

Example 2:

```
Input: nums = [-1,1,0,-3,3]
Output: [0,0,9,0,0]
```

Here is my code:

```
def inputArray():
    # creating an empty list
    lst = []
    
    # number of elements as input
    n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
    
    # iterating till the range
    for i in range(0, n):
        ele = int(input())
    
        lst.append(ele) # adding the element
        
    print(lst)
    return lst

l=inputArray()
array=[]
m=1
mul=1
for i in l:
    m*=i
    mul=m/i
for j in range(0,len(l)-1):
    array[j]=mul
    mul=1
print(array)
```

And I have the following eror: list assignment index out of range. I hope anyone could help me...

Comment: can you fix your code indentation please ?

Comment: You can't assign to `array[j]` to create a new element. Use `array.append(mul)`

Comment: I believe this is *infamous* Leetcode *prodcutExceptItself* prob. Req. is time O(n), space *O(1)*  - that's why made it harder...than it should be. ;-)

Comment: It also states "and without using the division operation". The O(1) space req is just extra credit.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/ ??? Given an integer array nums, return an array answer such that answer[i] is equal to the product of all the elements of nums except nums[i].

The product of any prefix or suffix of nums is guaranteed to fit in a 32-bit integer.

You must write an algorithm that runs in O(n) time and without using the division operation.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `array[j]=mul` but you never added any items to `array` so there's nothing to index. You have to either pre-fill the array or just append items to it instead.

Answer (score 1):

As `array` is empty, you cannot access it using indexing, but you don't need that, just append the product divided by the current value

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = []
m = 1

for value in l:
    m *= value
for value in l:
    result.append(m / value)

print(result)  # [24.0, 12.0, 8.0, 6.0]
```

That solution works only if 0 is not the list, if it is, you need more calcultation as you need to compute the product for each position

```
result = []
for idx, value in enumerate(l):
    m = 1
    for jdx, value in enumerate(l):
        if idx != jdx:
            m *= value
    result.append(m)
```